# Reputation missing from TP merge?

Tags: support, reputation, migration

I had posted on question to TP:SE, and the question was merged, but I don't seem to have the additional reputation points added (admittedly a small number).  My only evidence of missing the reputation is that I knew I was at a certain rep value for a long time because I was relatively inactive, and that value has only changed with one upvote (very recently).

Anyhow, the question is: [Consideration of static atomic displacements in electronic structure calculations](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/27193/consideration-of-static-atomic-displacements-in-electronic-structure-calculation)

My account was correctly associated between the two sites (as evidenced by the fact that I was properly associated with the question when it was merged).

Answer (score 4):

You can see a complete history of your reputation on your profile, using the "reputation" tab. In particular, if you look [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/users/2433/jen?tab=reputation&StartDate=2011-12-23), you will see all eight upvotes on that question explicitly accounted for. Now, if you know your pre-merge reputation and you're certain that it's the same as your post-merge reputation, I can't account for that. You could, in principle, go through the entire list on the reputation tab and verify that every vote you've received is accounted for there.